# It is possible force screen update after navigation.goBack() in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Exists some way to do this?

When I use `{ navigation.goBack() }` my changes wasn't does updated in the before screen, but using `navigate('MyObject', params )` the changes will be made without additional code to receive the changes.

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm; you're trying to change a value in a previous screen after changing it in the current screen, correct?

Comment: @rabbit87 Yeah... I am using Stack Navigation and... For me do'nt make sense the user change a value and execute two back's screens and the value is the old value beacuse in the back screens on click any button the values are updateds.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can think of for you to do this. The first is to use Redux and the second is to pass a function to the next screen that will update the previous screen. Example (for the second method) are below:

```
export default class screenA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 0};
  }

  updateValue=(val)=>{
    this.setState({value: val});
  }

  openScreenB=()=>{
    this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB', {
      updateValue: this.updateValue,
    });
  }
}

export default class screenB extends Component {
  updateClassAValue() {
    const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
    params.updateValue(20);
    this.props.navigation.pop();
  }
}
```

For Redux, I can't really say much about it since I haven't used it that much. However, it's made for this kind of purpose of sharing values between screen and easily updating the values.

Comment: this don't sounds like a good practice for me, my question is just for knows if exists some good way to do this because at press the device back, the pages back and after click in any button of ScreenA the values are updates, so the back button don't back the values but don't updates it  too

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. A value in a class state doesn't change because that value is contain only for that class's local state, if you passed it and change in another class, the changes will not affect the previous class. Which is why in my example I passed a function to screenB that would update screenA state. If you don't want to keep passing function to different screens, I can only think of using Redux to update the values as the value would be stored outside of any class.

Comment: My case is this: I have the stateA and I'm passing this state to ScreenB, in the ScreenB I'm change the value from stateA and when I'm call the ScreenA from the ScreenB the value in ScreenA is affected and this is nice! **but** if the user use the device back twice and returns for the ScreenA, the stateA it is with the old value **and** when the user click's in some button for example the value it is updated.

Comment: I need one of these two things: 1 - the values are always updated, 
no matter the way the user gets there, or 2 - using the back button from the device for back to the ScreenA, the ScreenA keep the previous state  and no update the values after click button.

Comment: For 1, sounds like Redux is the way to go. It stores the value outside of class and can send update to each class to uses the value whenever the value is updated. (https://redux.js.org). For 2, as far as I know, that is how it supposed to work, unless something tells screenA to change it's value, the value shouldn't change. Can you post your code here? Maybe someone can find what's changing value in screenA.